# How to make a function wait for parse.com's saveInBackground result? (in android)

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform

I have a code that saves data into parse.com, problem is, it doesnt wait for `saveInBackground` to finish, so it always return `false` (meaning no errors)  even there are errors found. Please help. thanks

```
    Boolean result;
public boolean insertToParseAndDB(String payType, int creditsLeft){
    result = false;
    ParseObject AudioRec = new ParseObject("Credit");
        AudioRec.put("payType", payType);
        AudioRec.put("creditsLeft", creditsLeft);
        AudioRec.put("isActive", true);
        AudioRec.put("subsType", 2);
        AudioRec.put("UserId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        {
        AudioRec.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException ex) {
                if (ex == null){
                    result = true;
                }
                else{
                    result = false;
                    Log.e("",ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }); 
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting ParseException?

Comment: No.. just to catch future ParseExceptions

Comment: do what you want to do in done method

Answer (score 2):

> it doesnt wait for saveInBackground to finish, so it always return
>   false

Because `saveInBackground` run in background Thread and provide callback methods to inform UI Thread when background task is completed.

So, use `done` method to perform next task.

> How to make a function wait for parse.com's saveInBackground result?

Use [ParseObject.save](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#save%28%29) or [ParseObject.saveAll](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveAll%28java.util.List%29) which run on main Thread and wait until option not finish(*Probably freeze UI or show ANR dialog*)

Comment: That bleepin sucks. There are so many use cases where it should wait until the ParseObject is saved on the background thread before updating the UI, such as after sending a message in a DM chat. Do you know what the alternative would be?